# add data to a 3-d array using R

Tags: r, loops, plyr, multidimensional-array

I have a series of functions in MATLAB that need to be converted into R. Unfortunately I do not know R all that well.

A major hurdle is loading csv 100 files that are each 50x86069 into a 100, 50, 86069 array.

I have the code set up to open/write an array, and then read each 50x86069 csv file as part of a loop.

```
l <- list.files(inputs)
data.array<-array(0,dim=c(100,50,86069))

# loop through the input files to get the data loaded into an array
for(i in 1:5)
in.file <- read.csv(paste(inputs,"/",l[[i]], sep = ""))

    in.file = in.file[,-1] ## remove the first column
```

Now I need to put in.file into data.array(i,50,86069).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks-

Comment: A reproducible example will go a long way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Is this question still up? If any of the answers solved your problem please mark it as answered (green check under the score) or provide further details about your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
> ar1 <- array(1:9, dim = c(3, 3))
> ar1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> ar2 <- array(10:18, dim = c(3, 3))
> ar3 <- array(19:27, dim = c(3, 3))
> ar.list <- list(ar1, ar2, ar3)
> bigarray <- array(NA, dim = c(3, 3, 3))
> for (i in 1:3) {
+     
+     intr <- vector("list", 3)
+     for(j in 1:3) {
+         intr[[j]] <- ar.list[[j]][i, ]
+     }
+     bigarray[, , i] <- do.call("rbind", intr)
+ }
> bigarray
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]   10   13   16
[3,]   19   22   25

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]   11   14   17
[3,]   20   23   26

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    6    9
[2,]   12   15   18
[3,]   21   24   27
```

Comment: I like the `laply` version better in terms of syntax, although `laply` might be a bit slower and more memory consuming.

Comment: ...and I think the `abind` function would work really well in your case.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I think we first need to establish that this is the desired result. :) Thanks for the tip on abind, I knew I was missing something.

Comment: Both solutions worked, but the solution by Roman worked better for the large data sets that i was loading.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can quite easily leverage the `laply` function from the `plyr` package to get the result you need:

```
list_csv = list.files("/path/to/csv_files/", pattern = "csv")
muli_dim_array = laply(list_csv, read.csv)
```

The `laply` function applies the function `read.csv` to the list `list_csv` and yields an array as result, hence the function name `la`ply. See Hadley's [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01) for more detail on `plyr`.

For an `rbind` like function that scales for multiple dimensions (>2), take a look at the `abind` function form the `abind` package. A solution using `abind` and `lapply`:

```
list_arrays = lapply(list_csv, read.csv)
n = length(dim(list_arrays[[1]]))
multi_dim_array = do.call("abind", list_arrays, along = n + 1)
```

This eliminates the need for `plyr` (but relies on `abind` :)), and might show different performance in terms of CPU time and RAM. Maybe some benchmarks could give some guidance in that case (also including the `for` loop based solution of @Roman).

At the end of the day I really like the short, to-the-point syntax of `plyr`, and I would first try that solution.

Comment: Paul and Roman -

Many thanks for your insight. While both solutions worked well, I think Roman's might be better suited for my needs.

One question that I have is using Roman's approach, how could I remove the first column out of each input ar variable?

The second question is that the input data will need values greater than one to be 1 something like ar[ar>0] <- 1

I would imagine both of these would be applied in the same loop, but am not able to get this to hapen without errors.

Thanks-